# ANOVA test and its advantages

Tags: anova

What are the advantages of using ANOVA test for large sample size and small sample size?
I have read the advantages of anova but i can't differentiate them into the ones that are related to large sample sizes and small sample sizes. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Small sample size, less power...I mean, I don't see how ANOVA are different in that term from other analysis. Can you precise your question?

Comment: Advantages compared to what? Under what circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

I saw the question from a different angle, correct me if I am off: When distributional assumptions are met, parametric tests, including ANOVA, are more powerful (or sensitive) than their non-parametric counterparts. Furthermore, ANOVA models can incorporate multiple factors and their interactions, repeated measures designs, random effects in mixed models etc. These advantages hold for any sufficient sample size, but designs with small sample sizes are less likely to have the degrees of freedom necessary for the abovementioned more complex models.